# rspec: raise_error usage to match error message

Tags: ruby, rspec

I raised an error using `raise(ConfigurationError.new(msg))`

I tried to test this with rspec:

```
expect {
  Base.configuration.username
}.to raise_error(ConfigurationError, message)
```

But this doesn't work. How can I test this? The goal is to match `message`.

Comment: Inside of "This doesn't work", better to provide specific errors.

Comment: By the way, raising the error as follows is equivalent: `raise ConfigurationError, msg`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can match error message with regex:

```
it { expect{ Foo.bar }.to raise_error(NoMethodError, /private/) }
```

This will check if `NoMethodError` raised with `private method` message not `undefined method`.

Will be useful because `NoMethodError.new` didn't pass tests even with same error message.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution is to use a block where you assert on various properties of `|error|`. Using the names in the original question:

```
expect { Base.configuration.username }
      .to(raise_error do |error|
        expect(error).to be_a(ConfigurationError)
        expect(error.message).to eq 'My configuration message'
      end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has been updated since 2016. This works.

```
it { expect{ Foo.bar }.to raise_error(NoMethodError, message) }
```

The message must match exactly.

rspec-core 3.12.2
rspec-expectations 3.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using rspec > 2.14.0 and take a look at this commit:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/commit/7f02b503d5ae48d1141b6465acd0a7a4e1bb84dd

```
it "passes if an error instance is expected" do
  s = StandardError.new
  expect {raise s}.to raise_error(s)
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the posters question of wanting to match the error message itself

Comment: This isn't the answer